# Как добавить индикатор загрузки во время работы AsyncTask?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть простой обычный `Fragment`содержащий `RecyclerView`

```
public class PhotoGalleryFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = "photoTag";

    private RecyclerView mPhotoRecyclerView;
    private List<GalleryItem> mItems = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean loading = true;
    public int mPage = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        new FetchItemsTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);

        mPhotoRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_photo_gallery_recyclerView);
        mPhotoRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
        mPhotoRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PhotoScrollListener());

        setupAdapter();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setupAdapter() {
        if (isAdded()) {
            if (mPhotoRecyclerView.getAdapter() == null)
                mPhotoRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PhotoAdapter(mItems));
            else
                mPhotoRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class PhotoScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

        private int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) {
                visibleItemCount = mPhotoRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mPhotoRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = ((GridLayoutManager) mPhotoRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).
                        findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        loading = false;
                        Log.e(TAG, "LAST ITEM");
                    }
                }
                if (!loading) {
                    loading = true;
                    mPage++;
                    new FetchItemsTask().execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTitleTextView;

        public PhotoHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView;
        }

        public void bindGalleryItem(GalleryItem item) {
            mTitleTextView.setText(item.toString());
        }
    }

    private class PhotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoHolder> {
        private List<GalleryItem> mGalleryItems;

        public PhotoAdapter(List<GalleryItem> items) {
            mGalleryItems = items;
        }

        @Override
        public PhotoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            return new PhotoHolder(textView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoHolder holder, int position) {
            GalleryItem item = mGalleryItems.get(position);
            holder.bindGalleryItem(item);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mGalleryItems.size();
        }
    }

    private class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<GalleryItem>> {

        @Override
        protected List<GalleryItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return new FlickrFetchr().fetchItems(mPage, mItems);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<GalleryItem> galleryItems) {
            mItems = galleryItems;
//            mItems.addAll(galleryItems);
            setupAdapter();
        }
    }

    public static PhotoGalleryFragment newInstance() {
        PhotoGalleryFragment fragment = new PhotoGalleryFragment();

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

По логике работы `ScrollListener` по достижению края списка запускается `AsyncTasc` который запускает отправку запроса, по завершению которого обновляется (дополняется новыми элементами) список элементов `RecyclerView'a`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно добавить возможность визуального отображения процесса загрузки (отправка запроса > получение ответа > парсинг ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользовался следующим решением. В `AsyncTasc` добивал `ProgressDialog`. И мой класс, унаследованный от `AsyncTask` стал выглядеть следующим образом

```
private class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<GalleryItem>> {

        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        private Context c;

        public FetchItemsTask(Context c) {
            this.c = c;
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            this.mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<GalleryItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return new FlickrFetchr().fetchItems(mPage, mItems);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<GalleryItem> galleryItems) {
            mItems = galleryItems;
//            mItems.addAll(galleryItems);
            setupAdapter();
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<GalleryItem>> {
      ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }
        @Override
        protected List<GalleryItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return new FlickrFetchr().fetchItems(mPage, mItems);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<GalleryItem> galleryItems) {
            mItems = galleryItems;
//            mItems.addAll(galleryItems);
            setupAdapter();
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE); 
        }
    }
```

в XML

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: а во второй строке откуда взять view? Ведь мы еще не раздули основной фрагмент

Comment: @mamba0767 по привычке добавил) помогло решение?)

Comment: Нет, пробовал предложенный вами метод с разными вариантами - в итоге воспользовался вот таким методом. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538338/progressdialog-in-asynctask Но все равно благодарен